# Laravel Eloquent: Does $pay->sum('amount'); executes another query on database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have this code:

```
$fee = sys_fee::where('payment', '=', 'Paid')->get();
$totalFee = $fee->sum('amount');
```

Can anyone tell me, whether traverses database for both of these lines above or does it only go to database once in the first line?

In simple, does the following line, execute another query on database or does it only work with the array?

```
$totalFee = $fee->sum('amount');
```

My current understanding is that it doesn't execute another query on database.

Comment: I doesn't make another SQL call. Another way of debugging would be installing some SQL debugger or using DB::getQueryLog()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$fee` is an objection of Collection, the sum() method doesn't make SQL calls, instead it goes through all the elements of that collection.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sum